# Order By Unique Cases SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Afternoon All,

I am pretty green with SQL and trying to run a query to find the latest in customer reference.

I have a table like this

```
LYJX001 | AB1
LYJX001 | AB2
LYJX001 | ABJ
TATT001 | AB1
TATT001 | AB3
```

Basically the first column are unique to each customer the final 3 are linked quotes. I wish to get a list of the most recent quote for each unique customer. The quotes work from 1-9 and then A-Z after the 'AB' prefix. AB'J' would be considered a later quote than AB'1' for example.

I know an ORDER BY puts these in the correct order but I just wish to return the latest quote per each LYJX001 & TATT001 for example. So from the above table I would want to return just.

```
LYJX001 | ABJ
TATT001 | AB3
```

After my select statement.

Any help would be appreciated I am probably overthinking what I wish to do and getting the syntax wrong :/

Ta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select first_column, max(second_column)
from your_table
group by first_column
```